# Subdirectory Rewrite | Include All Relative Stuff

Tags: php, regex, apache, mod-rewrite, include

I'm trying to hide actual sub-directory from url path using mod_rewrite.

The folder actual name is **members** and i want users to use **area** instead.

The code I'm using works but no images or relative stuff is loading. The rule is missing certain parameters. Can you point me in the right direction?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^area/$ /members/$1
```

Like I said, code works and index page loads, but all relative images, includes and other don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't rewrite existing files:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

And more likely

```
RewriteRule ^area/include/(*.)$ /include/$1
RewriteRule ^area/images/(*.)$ /images/$1
```

Comment: Worked. Fine. I had to only include the first two Cond.